# vue multiselect lost reactivity on updating v-model

Tags: vue.js, vue-reactivity, vue-multiselect

My Vue multiselect component:

```js
<multiselect 
    required 
    label="role" 
    track-by="role" 
    :close-on-select="false"
    :clear-on-select="false" 
    :preserve-search="true" 
    :preselect-first="false"
    :multiple="true" 
    :options="roles" 
    v-model="role.roleID" 
>
    <template slot="selection" slot-scope="{ values, isOpen }">
        <span
            class="multiselect__single"
            v-if="values.role &amp;&amp; !isOpen"
        >
            {{ values.role }} 
        </span>
    </template>                
</multiselect>
```

And data method:

```js
data: function () {
    return {
        role: {
            role: '',
            description: '',
            scopeLevel: '',
            roleID: ''
        },
        roles: [],
    }
},
```

And when I make an API call, I get the below response:

```js
let responce = [
    {            
        'id': '1',
        'role': 'Test role'            
    }, {
        'id': '2',
        'role': 'Test role 2'  
    }
]
```

When I try to bind this response to multiselect `v-model`, i.e. `role.roleID`:

```js
this.role.roleID = responce
```

The multiselect component loses reactivity.

Let me know what I am doing wrong here. Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain what happens after you set the data from API response. doesn't it show in the multiselect selection or?

Comment: @ChathurangaK It displays as selected options but the multiselect components loses its reactivity. i.e. when i select next option it does not display on frontend.

Answer (score 1):

Without directly assigning the role, try using `Vue setter`.

```
this.$set(this.role, 'roleID', responce);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some mistakes:

1. the `role` variable in your `data` section is initialized as Object - but it should be an Array or otherwise you can not select multiple options
2. the `v-model` is bound to `roleID` - but your response does not have such a property

```html
<multiselect v-model="role" />
```

```js
data: () => ({
  roles: [], // the list of all options
  role: [], // the list of currently selected options
})
```

```js
this.roles = response
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The thing is, my 'v-model' is 'role.roleID' not 'role', i.e. i am binding the list of currently selected options to 'role.roleID'. In above question i have given it string declaration but even if i changed it to string its not working.
One more thing i observed is before assigning the response to 'role.roleID' if i console it then it shows "
```[{…}, {…}, __ob__: Observer]``` and when i assign the response array to it and then console it it shows ```[{…}, {…}]```. I am not sure what that ```__ob__: Observer``` thing is but thats the difference i found.

Comment: ** consider "array" instead of string on 3rd line of above comment. So it will be 
...i have given it string declaration but even if i changed it to "Array" its not working

Comment: As I said earlier - `role.roleID` could work if your select was limited to single item selection only. But you have explicitly set `:multiple="true"` and so it is mandatory for your `v-model` to be bound to an Array. Therefore if you insist to bind to `role.roleID` - you should initialize `roleID` as an Array, not as String, and assign the API response to the `roles` array - not to `role.roleID`